# Cuál es la implicación de b?

Tags: php

***Por qué esto no me arroja error:***

```
 <?php

    echo b"Porqué sucede esto";

    ?>
```

***Pero esto sí:***

```
<?php

    echo c"Porqué sucede esto";

    ?>
```

*Como puedo verse solo cambié la `'b'` por una `'c'` , y ahí si arroja **ERROR**, por qué?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.type-juggling.php), `b` se usa para conversión de tipos binarios.

> El forzado (binary) y el soporte del prefijo `b` fueron añadidos en PHP
>   5.2.1

Esto fue introducido porque al parecer en PHP 6 había un proyecto de incluir el manejo de cadenas binarias, el cual parece estar abandonado (ver al final).

Por tanto al hacer:

```
echo b"Porqué sucede esto";
```

No da error, porque PHP intenta forzar un binario desde esa cadena.

Es como si hicieras:

```
 echo (int) "Porqué sucede esto";
```

Sólo que ahí verías la conversión realizada y se imprimiría `0` en pantalla.

Hubo un intento de declarar este uso como obsoleto, con la intención posterior de eliminarlo del core de PHP, según el reporte: [PHP RFC: Binary String Deprecation](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/binary_string_deprecation)

> En la versión 5.2.1, el prefijo `b` y el cast (binary) se introdujeron
>   para compatibilidad directa con el proyecto PHP-6. Sin embargo, ese
>   proyecto nunca llegó a ser y nadie puede decir si alguna vez será el
>   enfoque elegido en un posible intento futuro de implementar cadenas
>   binarias. Sin embargo, estos son aún aceptados por el escáner de
>   idioma, aunque ignorado a partir de entonces.

Y luego dice:

> Este RFC pretende despreciar el prefijo, ya que no produce ningún
>   efecto en la cadena literal y el molde binario, ya que **es lo mismo
>   que la conversión de cadena**.
>
> La implementación propuesta consiste en lanzar un `E_DEPRECATED`
>   durante la compilación cuando se utiliza el prefijo o el molde. **En
>   una versión posterior mayor de PHP, el soporte para estos debe ser
>   eliminado**.
>
> Por último, este RFC también incluye un parche para la documentación
>   para eliminar la referencia a este elenco en la página de [Conversión
>   de Tipos](http://php.net/manual/es/language.types.type-juggling.php) y otro para la especificación del idioma.

No obstante, como ha señalado @Xerif en un comentario, dicho intento fracasó. En el enlace del RFC citado más arriba dice que se requería 2/3 de votos a favor para aprobar este intento, pero no se llegó a dicho consenso (la votación terminó con 19 votos a favor y 13 en contra).

¿El motivo?, no aparecía indicado en ninguna parte. [Yo lo he preguntado en el hilo de Github donde se discutía sobre el asunto](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/pull/188):

> Do you know why this RFC was rejected? And, it can be deprecated in
>   PHP 8? Thanks.

Y ha habido la siguiente respuesta una hora después:

> you can find the discussion here and more here The RFC itself is found
>   here. Given the rejection, it is very unlikely it will get deprecated
>   any time soon.
>
> ---
>
> usted puede encontrar la discusión [aquí](https://externals.io/message/96743) y también [aquí](https://externals.io/message/98131). El
>   RFC en sí mismo se encuentra [aquí](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/binary_string_deprecation). **Teniendo en cuenta el
>   rechazo, es muy poco probable que sea declarada obsoleta en un futuro
>   próximo**.

Comment: Solo una cosilla, el RFC que indicas parece que fue rechazado de momento.

Comment: Es cierto, no me había percatado de ello @Xerif, ahora edito la pregunta.